# I keep getting stuck in an infinite loop when testing a string using a function in a for loop

Tags: javascript

When I test a string using the inputName function, I get stuck in an infinite loop that keeps displaying the alert() functions in the browser. I'm not sure the logic behind why it's happening. Note this is for a school assignment and I'm required to use a for loop and a function with parameters to test inputted data called employeeName. The function tests to see if the data is null, empty or a number before returning a value.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function inputName(name) 
{
    var flag;

    do
    {

        flag = false;
        if (name == null)
        {
            alert("You have hit the 'Cancel' button!");
            return name;
            flag = false;
        }
        if (name == "")
        {
            alert("You tried entering no name!");
            flag = true;
        }
        else if (!isNaN(name))
        {
            alert("You tried entering a number!");
            flag = true;
        }
        else if (name.length < 2)
        {
            alert("You tried entering a name less than 2 characters!");
            flag = true;
        }
    } while (flag);
    return name;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

// DECLARATIONS
var numEmployees;
var employeeName;
var testName;


// INPUT
numEmployees = prompt("Enter the number of employees");

// PROCESSING
for (var index = 1; index <= numEmployees; index++)
{
    employeeName = prompt("Enter a name.");
    testName = inputName(employeeName);
}

// OUTPUT

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I really wonder what the teacher is trying to teach right there :3 Validating a single input with a `for` (which by the way is a `do ... while`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prompt the user to correct the name.

```
var getName = function() {
    var name;

    do {
        name = prompt("Enter a name.");
    } while(!validateName(name));

    return name;
};

var validateName = function(name) {
    if (name == null) {
        alert("You have hit the 'Cancel' button!");
        return true;
    }

    if (name == "") {
        alert("You tried entering no name!");
        return false;
    }
    else if (!isNaN(name)) {
        alert("You tried entering a number!");
        return false;
    }
    else if (name.length < 2) {
        alert("You tried entering a name less than 2 characters!");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not prompting for a new name inside of the loop, the name never changes so you keep testing the same string over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using a `for` loop; that's a `do ... while` loop.

The problem is that you set "flag" to `true`, but nothing happens to set it to `false` before you loop around and set it to `true` again. If the function starts off with the "name" being empty, a number, or a single-character string, that loop will just go on and on.